# Woocommerce Related Product exclude current product in Sub categories

Tags: php, html, arrays, woocommerce

I Having trouble to exclude the current product in related product Woocommerce,
now i have change the related product from category to subcategory (without child). SO the related product will only display the subcategory product (same subcategory) but now it will also display the current product. anyone one have solution> Thank You

```
  if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

global $product, $woocommerce_loop;

if ( empty( $product ) || ! $product->exists() ) {
    return;
}

if ( ! $related = $product->get_related( $posts_per_page ) ) {
    return;
}

$cats_array = array(0);

// get categories
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->id, 'product_cat' );

// select only the category which doesn't have any children
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $children = get_term_children( $term->term_id, 'product_cat' );
    if ( !sizeof( $children ) )
    $cats_array[] = $term->term_id;
}



$args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
    'exclude' => array( $cur_product_id ),
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'post__not_in' => array( $cur_product_id ),
    'no_found_rows' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $cats_array
        ),
    )
));

$products                    = new WP_Query( $args );
$woocommerce_loop['name']    = 'related';
$woocommerce_loop['columns'] = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products_columns', $columns );

if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <div class="related products">

        <h2><?php _e( 'Related Products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

    </div>

<?php endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is $cur_product_id variable!
Change with this:

```
$product->get_the_id()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You so much. I found the solution

By adding this

$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->id, 'product_cat' );

and this 'post__not_in' => array( $cur_product_id ),

Here is the code

```
 if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

global $product, $woocommerce_loop;

if ( empty( $product ) || ! $product->exists() ) {
    return;
}

if ( ! $related = $product->get_related( $posts_per_page ) ) {
    return;
}

$cats_array = array(0);
// The current product id (Woocommerce version retro compatible)
$cur_product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id; 
// get categories
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->id, 'product_cat' );

// select only the category which doesn't have any children
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $children = get_term_children( $term->term_id, 'product_cat' );
    if ( !sizeof( $children ) )
    $cats_array[] = $term->term_id;
}

$args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
    'exclude' => array( $cur_product_id ),
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'post__not_in' => array( $cur_product_id ),
    'no_found_rows' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $cats_array
        ),
    )
));

$products                    = new WP_Query( $args );
$woocommerce_loop['name']    = 'related';
$woocommerce_loop['columns'] = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products_columns', $columns );

if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <div class="related products">

        <h2><?php _e( 'Related Products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

    </div>

<?php endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```